# Javascript 'this' and asynchronously post method

Tags: javascript, post, asynchronous

I'm kinda new on javascript, and I've having difficulties (for 2 days now) in implementing the following:

Consider I have an Object(), 'engine', which I want it to respond differently according to a post's content. I.e. there is an action by the user, the engine interprets the action, sends a request to the server, and server responds, and the 'engine' acts accordingly.

As a minimal example of the desired behavior, I present an 'engine' which hypothetically is receiving mouse click's position (receiveClickEvent), sends it trough a 'post' (requestByAsyncPost), and responds according to its content (respondToRequest):

A small function for doing the post

```
function requestByAsyncPost(content, funct)
{
/* some initialization missing here to not confuse the reader */
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            funct(xmlhttp.response);
        }
    }
xmlhttp.open("POST","foobar.php", true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send(content);
}

var engine = new Object()
engine.respondToRequest = function(content) {/*implementation*/ }
```

a small piece of code which I want to be activated when a mouse click occurs (doesn't matter now how it is triggered)

```
engine.receiveClickEvent = function(position)
{
    var funct = function(content)
    {
         this.respondToRequest(content); //<<<---- I want to refer engine's 'this'
    }
    requestByAsyncPost('request=click&position=['+position[0]+','+position[1]+')', funct);
}
```

This is not working the way I want because the "this" is inside the function funct. How can I implement this kind of behavior?

Comment: wow so many answers in such a short time, and all the same ;)

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering the same... Its unfair, now how am I suppose to choose the 'right' one?

Comment: just select the one you like most; or one which explains the problem and the solution well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must remember outer `this` by this way or other. Like:

```
engine.receiveClickEvent = function(position)
{
    var self = this;
    var funct = function(content)
    {
         self.respondToRequest(content); //<<<---- 'self' refers engine's 'this'
    }; // <<<--- btw, missed semicolon
    requestByAsyncPost('request=click&position=['+position[0]+','+position[1]+')', funct);
}; // <<<--- btw, here, too :-)
```

Comment: In upcomiong version 6 of ECMAScript standard (the official standard of what is known as JavaScript) there is new shorter syntax of functions added which do not use own `this` but outer one, there you would do just: `var funct = (content) => { this.respondToRequest(content); };` and it would work.

Answer (score 1):

I constantly stumple upon the same problem, when heavily using anonymous AJAX callback functions.

This is how i "work around" this type of problem:

```
var engine = function (args) {
    // store a reference to "this" inside a variable for reuse in another scope
    var me = this;
    var fetchSomething = function (args) {
        var req = $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: url,
            success: function(data) {
                // use "me" instead of "this", because "this" is scope dependant
                me.doSomething(data);
            }
        });
    }
    var doSomething = function (data) {
        // some logic here.
    }  
} 
foo = new engine({arg: 'foo', arg2: 'bar'});
foo.fetchSomething(url);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always save the current this in a variable and then use it wherever you want:

```
var that = this;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
engine.receiveClickEvent = function(position)
{

    var me = this;
    var funct = function(content)
    {
         me.respondToRequest(content); //<<<---- I want to refer engine's 'this'
    }
    requestByAsyncPost('request=click&position=['+position[0]+','+position[1]+')', funct);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand the question, but I think what you might be looking for is defining a var this in the engine object.. then in your function you use that variabl instead of this..

i.e. :

```
var engine = function(){
var self = this;

receiveClickEvent = function(position)
{
    var funct = function(content)
    {
         **self**.respondToRequest(content); //<<<---- I want to refer engine's 'this'
    }
    requestByAsyncPost('request=click&position=['+position[0]+','+position[1]+')',   funct);
}

}
```